# Multi language support without plugin in ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, multilingual

Following is my constant file in which I am setting language of ionic app.

```
@Injectable()
export class Constant {
  public static selectedLang :string = 'EN';

  static setLanguage(languageCode : string){
    Constant.selectedLang = languageCode;

  }
  readonly data: any = {
    "EN": {
      //declared English variables used to be all over the application
             FORGOT_PASSWORD : "Forgot Password",
          }
    "MR": {
             //marathi variables
             FORGOT_PASSWORD : "पासवर्ड विसरलात",
           }
    "HI":{
             //Hindi variables
             FORGOT_PASSWORD : "पासवर्ड भूल गए",
         }
   LANG: any = this.data[Constant.selectedLang];
 }
```

I use this variables in HTML in following way:

```
<div>
   <h2>{{CON.LANG.FORGOT_PASSWORD}}</h2>
   <p>{{CON.LANG.FORGOT_PASSWORD}}</p>
</div>
```

ts file where I set language:

```
import {Constant} from "../../../../constants";
class ForgotPassword {
    constructor(public CON: Constant){}

    setLanguage(languageCode : string){
       Constant.setLanguage(languageCode);
    }
 }
```

Here, I want to keep English as my default language. When user explicitly changes the language by calling the function, then only language should be changed. But the issue is Even if user calls the function to change language, its not changed. App is always showing English variables.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do with help of pipe

Comment: @PareshGami https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/how-to-build-ionic-3-multi-language-app-b5a34d105b9 like this ?

Comment: In question you says without plugin but that is one kind of plugin. But you can use it that was plugin of angular not native plugin so you can use it

Comment: @PareshGami Actually I have implemented this Constant file approach. I cant rollback all the changes at this stage. Can you please suggest anything which can be implemented in minimum efforts in current approach ?

Comment: Sure i can help create stackbliz working copy with pipe then I will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got what I was doing wrong earlier. I made 'data' and 'LANG' variables of Constant file normal instead of static. And changed the setLanguage function as follows.

```
 setLanguage(languageCode : string){
    this.selectedLang = languageCode;
    this.LANG = this.data[this.selectedLang]; //line added
  }
```

Also, I stored my selectedLanguage variable from component to session storage so that, language will not be changed after I close and open the app again.

```
 setLanguage(languageCode : string){
    this.CON.setLanguage(languageCode);
    this.sessionProvider.setLanguage(languageCode);
  }
```